# I want to add my own css in tailwindcss. It is not adapted

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using next.js and tailwinds.
I want to hide the scroll bars.
I wrote a style to hide scrollbars in style.css, but it is not applied.

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to extend it like this:

```
@layer base {
    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        scrollbar-width: none;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: The message Unknown at rule @layercss(unknownAtRules) will be displayed.

Comment: What should I do?